# Searching for Users Facebook Albums with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API to query the users Photo Albums (I am using the Facebook SDK for Android). I am sending the Request me/albums to Facebook and I receive all albums. After receiving my result I have to filter the result list because I do not want to show the albums which have the attribute can_upload=false.

Can I send any parameter with my request to Facebook which returns only albums with the attribute can_upload=true?

Regards

Michael

Comment: `me/albums?can_upload=true` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Facebook to filter results for you, you need to use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album).

```
SELECT name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner= USER_ID AND can_upload = true
```